# Using opam from behind a firewall

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm wondering what I need to setup so that opam will download packages through a proxy server if I'm behind a firewall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`opam` uses `curl`, so you can simply setup `http_proxy`, `HTTPS_PROXY` or `ALL_PROXY` environment variable to point to your proxy server.